# R, shiny, prevent error until field is calculated

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a shiny application, and I would like there to be a field like this that displays the probability someone will return (given a bunch of underlying models):

[image]

And it pretty much works, except its in decimal form:
[image]

The code pasting into that box looks like this:

```
paste(a$result)
```

I can get it to look "correct" and say '83%' for instance, instead of 0.83000.....

by using this code:

```
paste(  c( round(a$result, digits=2))*100,"%")
```

But the problem is.... while this code does work, until you hit the "calculate" button, it looks like this:

[image]

I wish I could provide some sample data to try but given the interactiveness of the shiny app, that'd be very hard.  Is there a simple solution?

Comment: Worked perfect!  Want to  make it an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the function `shiny::req` to make sure required values are present before performing the calculation. For example

```
paste(c( round(req(a$result), digits=2))*100,"%")
```

Comment: This is a very helpful hint!+1